# Is there a general word (not zoomorphise) that describes treating a non-living thing as if it were alive?

Tags: single-word-requests

We commonly *anthropomorphise* or *personify* non-living things by giving them human characteristics: "the angry storm".

We *zoomorphise* things by giving them animal characteristics: "the storm roared".

But what word would describe giving general (not necessarily animal) attributes of living things to non-living things: "the storm died"?

A more specific example would be treating geomorphological landforms as if they have a life-cycle, but in the context of drawing parallels with the life-cycles of trees and forests. The additional human or animal connotations of "anthropomorphise" and "zoomorphise" do not apply, so it would be good if there were a more general word for this practice.

This is very similar to the question "[Equivalent for "personify" that's not human-specific](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/271044/equivalent-for-personify-thats-not-human-specific)". However the accepted answer in that case was "zoomorphise" since the OP was talking about a self-driving car being "hunted" [like an animal], whereas I am looking for the right word for a more general case.

Comment: You already have your answer. Calling a storm angry, as a human might be, is classically *anthropomorphic*. Animating a storm is just figurative speech.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I am specifically looking for the word that applies to the *general* case of treating something as if it were alive. Being the general case, "anthropomorphic", or "zoomorphic" could indeed both apply to my example "the storm died". However, the first suggests treating the storm as if it were a person, and the second an animal, whereas 'being alive' is much more general. The aim of this question is to find the word with the right meaning, not that fits this simple example.

Comment: Did you have some reason for discarding *biomorph*? ([paywalled OED link](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19236#eid20353923))

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's a term for this, any more than there's a term for comparing things to fish, or insects, or blancmange. (Comparing things/animals to people is common, and comparing living things to machines, and not much else.) Since there's not even a single English word for living things, including plants, animals (and possibly fungi). But good luck!

Comment: @StuartF The word you're looking for is *life*; *biology* studies all life, no matter its domain or kingdom.

Comment: The best chatGPT can come up with ***Personify, Animize, Enliven, Endow with life, Vitalize.*** I think what that means is the answer to OP's question is *There is no such word*. Zoomorphise is close, but that means to attribute an *animal* nature to something; treating a growing crystal like a growing plant wouldn't be covered by that.

Comment: @tchrist Nice one, though *biomorph* seems to refer to form rather than other attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try:

> **animism**, *n.*
> **2.** The attribution of life and personality (and sometimes a soul) to inanimate objects and natural phenomena; = ANIMATISM* *n.*
> <sub>[selected example:]</sub>
>  <sub>1973     *Jrnl.
> Genetic Psychol.* 123 219     Piaget..observed that many
> preadolescent children tend to ascribe life and consciousness to inert
> objects, a phenomenon that he called ‘animism’.</sub>
>  <sub>Source:
> [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

The problem with this word is that it’s usually used to refer to a belief system. Here’s [what Wikipedia has to say on animism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animism):

> **Animism** (from Latin: *anima* meaning ‘breath, spirit, life’) is the belief that objects, places, and creatures all possess a distinct
> spiritual essence. Animism perceives all things—animals, plants,
> rocks, rivers, weather systems, human handiwork, and in some cases
> words—as animated and alive.

But if it’s okay to believe the storm actually died, go for it.

*<sub>See also: **animatism** *noun* **:** attribution of consciousness and personality but not of individual spirit to such natural phenomena as thunderstorms and earthquakes and to such objects as plants and stones. Source: [Merriam-Webster — *animatism*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/animatism)</sub>

Comment: In verb form, to *animise*, though this seems very rare. Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the verb **animate**.

> In this novel, the character Joe **animates** almost everything he describes:

> > *The ice began to **crawl** across the surface of the pond as the temperature dropped.*
> >
> > *Specks of dust **swim** in a ray of sunshine*.
> >
> > *The clock **oozed** slowly towards evening.*
> >
> > *The mystery slowly **shed its skin***.

Compare:

> The imagination in general **animates** things; the mystical imagination not only animates them, but makes them move, and tends to personify them.
> [Contemporary Writers VII. MISS EDITH SITWELL, by Edwin Muir in *The Nation*, vol. 39, no. 1 (1926) (my emphasis) ]